# Helm lookup a value from configmap and verify against dictionary key exist then print value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

CM:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  cluster: cluster1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: testmap
  namespace: test
```

Code inside _helper.tpl:

```
{{- define "jupyterBaseUrl" -}}
{{- $placeHolder := .Values.placeHolder }}
{{- if not .Values.placeHolder }}
{{- $ConfigMap := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" .Release.Namespace "testmap") }}
{{- if $ConfigMap }}
{{- $placeHolder = index $ConfigMap.data "cluster"}}
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.cluster }}
{{- if hasKey $key $placeHolder }}
{{ printf "%s" $value }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

print the value on deployment.yaml:

```
value: {{- include jupyterBaseUrl . }}
```

place holder variable in value.yaml.

```
placeHolder:
```

Dictionary values in values.yaml

```
cluster:
  cluster1: region1
```

I am trying to verify if cluster name match from configmap then print the region value, the error I am getting with this try is:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: test/templates/deployment.yaml:76:26: executing "test/templates/deployment.yaml" at <"spark.jupyterBaseUrl">: can't give argument to non-function "jupyterBaseUrl"
```

Comment: This logic might be easier to write in controller code in Go using the Kubernetes API.  Why do you need this particular external dependency; can you rewrite your chart's configuration to be self-contained, and not need `lookup`?

Comment: If i understand correctly instead of handling the lookup from template rather using k8s controller section, but this is not our requirment. I have to create a code as mentioned.

Comment: Why do you need the external ConfigMap?  Can you `helm install --set-string jupyterBaseUrl=region1`, or put a similar setting in a per-environment `helm install -f` values file, and directly use `.Values.jupyterBaseUrl` without this indirect step?

Answer (score 0):

the above code roughly look fine, but there are few settings which I have missed. find below the full solution.

correct function would be:

```
{{- define "jupyterBaseUrl" -}}
{{- $clusterNameEmptyString := .Values.clusterNameEmptyString }}
{{- if not .Values.clusterNameEmptyString }}
{{- $ConfigMap := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" .Release.Namespace "testmap") }}
{{- if $ConfigMap }}
{{- $clusterNameEmptyString = index $ConfigMap.data "cluster"}}
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.clusterName }}
{{- if eq $key  $clusterNameEmptyString }}
{{- if typeOf $value | eq "string" }}
{{- printf "%s" $value }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```